# Treat rollbacks from the same user as single edits

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, rollbacks, rollback-wars

When a single user makes multiple edits to a single post within a 5 minute period these get merged into one single edit in the revision history to avoid excessive verbosity.

When handling rollbacks the same does not currently happen - the history can show multiple edits from one person in a very short timespan.

It should happen in the rollback case too because:

1. When it happens it usually indicates correcting a mistake with the version that was picked, not abusive behaviour.
2. It would help reduce a class of spurious "possible rolllback war" automatically raised flags.